# Email Script Code Based On Formula Change in Google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail, google-sheets

I used a code that I copied from someone and edited for the content that I needed. However, I have little to no experience and I am sure I have destroyed any functionality. I am trying to have an email sent to me when a formula in a Google Sheet updates to a certain value for a range in my Sheet from F5:F12.

Here is the current version

```js
function sendEmail(email_address, email_subject, email_message) {
  var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet 1").getActiveRange().getValues().toString();
  if (value = ("☁")) { 
        MailApp.sendEmail('user1...@myemail.com', 'My Subject','My Message : ');
   
}
 else { 
    if (value = ("☀")) 
    MailApp.sendEmail('user2...@myemail.com', 'My Subject','My Message : ')
 }
}
```

I've tried lots of snippets of code from both StackOverflow but I haven't been able to modify one that works due to my basic understanding.

-----------Update---------------

```js
function onEdit(e){
    try{
        if(
            e.range.getRowIndex() >= 5 && 
            e.range.getRowIndex() <= 12 &&
            e.range.getColumnIndex() == 6
        ){
            if(e.range.getValue().charCodeAt(0) == 9729){
                MailApp.sendEmail('xxx.xxx@gmail.com', 'Target Missed', 'View Spreadsheet');
            }else if(e.range.getValue().charCodeAt(0) == 9728){ 
                MailApp.sendEmail('xxxx@gmail.com', 'Target Met', 'View Spreadsheet');
            }
        }
    }catch(error){
        Logger.log(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your code is supposed to send an email when a cell in the F5:F12 range is edited and contains only "☁" or "☀", then your code should look something like this:

```
function onEdit(e){
    try{
        if(
            e.range.getRowIndex() >= 5 && 
            e.range.getRowIndex() <= 12 &&
            e.range.getColumnIndex() == 6
        ){
            if(e.range.getValue().charCodeAt(0) == 9729){
                MailApp.sendEmail('user1...@myemail.com', 'My Subject', 'My Message:');
            }else if(e.range.getValue().charCodeAt(0) == 9728){ 
                MailApp.sendEmail('user2...@myemail.com', 'My Subject', 'My Message:');
            }
        }
    }catch(error){
        Logger.log(error);
    }
}
```

9729 and 9728 are the decimal Unicode values for "☁" and "☀" respectively.

Your code had a number of fatal syntax errors. I think you would probably benefit from studying a [basic JavaScript tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/).

Comment: I appreciate the response and the link. I changed the code and updated the email address and made changes to the Sheet that would prompt the formula to change the cell to reflect the characters "☁" and "☀", but I didn't receive and email. So I then attempted to input the characters directly into the cell, but it didn't produce and email either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Post your updated code so we can see where you're going wrong.

Comment: Try running the code from the script editor by clicking on "Run" then "onEdit". You'll probably be prompted to allow your script to access spreadsheets and send emails. You only have to do this once, then the permissions should be set permanently.

Answer (score 0):

You need an **onEdit** trigger to run the code:

[Google Documentation - Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

### Quote from Documentation:

> For example, the sample code below shows a simple onEdit(e) trigger
>   for a Google Sheets script that uses the event object to determine
>   which cell was edited.

Here is some code from that documentation with Logger.log() statements added by me:

```
function onEdit(e){
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  Logger.log('onEdit ran!');
  Logger.log('value of e: ' + e);
  var range = e.range;
  Logger.log('This is the range: ' + range);
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
}
```

So, that code will get you information about what cell was edited.  Then you'll need to compare that, to cells in your range of F5:F12.

Note the `Logger.log()' statements.  To view what is printed to the LOG, click the VIEW menu, and the LOGS.

Verify that the function is running by viewing the log.  Also check the EXECUTION TRANSCRIPT under the VIEW menu to see any error messages.

Please update your question with any LOG messages and/or errors, and make a comment below.